# Is there a way to make chrome extension storage.sync data persistant when uninstalling and reinstalling the extension?

Tags: google-chrome

I am writing a chrome extension to link together data in two separate sites. The extension uses chrome.storage.sync to store pairs of keys, to the data in each site. i.e. so that the user can click to navigate directly between the linked pages.

The problem is that if I uninstall and reinstall the extension all the data gets deleted and I lose all my links. I don't want to involve another server storing data (and all the headaches that bring, user accounts, logins, GPDR etc), I would like to just store everything in the chrome sync storage.

Is there a way to make the chrome.storage.sync data more persistent?

Answer (score -2):

This API has been optimized to meet the specific storage needs of extensions. It provides the same storage capabilities as the localStorage API with the following key differences:

User data can be automatically synced with Chrome sync (using storage.sync).
Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.
A user's extension settings can be persisted even when using split incognito behavior.
It's asynchronous with bulk read and write operations, and therefore faster than the blocking and serial localStorage API.
User data can be stored as objects (the localStorage API stores data in strings).
Enterprise policies configured by the administrator for the extension can be read (using storage.managed with a schema).

Comment: This is just a generic description of the api. It does not address the question at all